# Is it possible to find $\sum_{k=1}^nkr_k$ if $\sum_{k=1}^nr_k=N$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is it possible to find $\sum_{k=1}^nkr_k$ if $\sum_{k=1}^nr_k=N$?

The background of the question is related to multinomial coefficients and the need for the indexes to sum up to some $N$.

Comment: Consider the two sequences when $r_k=0$ everywhere except $k=1$ and another sequences where it is zero everywhere except $k=n$.

Comment: If you don't have a particular form for $r_k$ you can't do better than Kamal's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a formula for $\sum_{k=1}^nr_k=s(n)$ for any $n$, then the sum in question is $\sum_{k=1}^ns(k)$. To prove this, you can write your sum as
$r_1+2r_2+3r_3+…=(r_1)+(r_2+r_2)+(r_3+r_3+r_3)+…$ then write this as a sum of rows where the first term in each parentheses is in the first row and so on. [image]
Instead of summing up and down as we did for the original sum, we are now summing from left to right.

Comment: Meaning we won't be able to find it since we don't know $r_k$ and so neither $s(k)$

Comment: @JoanS.GuillametF. But you might be able to sum $s(k)$ in your situation.